# ASP.NET data annotations - A Number or a specific string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a field to which I want to apply the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute` to thus

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
```

But I'd like this field to be a string because there is another value that I'd like it be able to have and that is "Unlimited".  Is there some attribute or combination of attributes I can use to say "allow any positive integer or the string "Unlimited"?

Thanks,

Sachin

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular expression like in this question:
[RegEx that matches positive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466002/regex-that-matches-positive-numbers)

Hope that helps. Thanks.