# RE2 RegEx that matches positive numbers

Tags: regex, re2

I need an RE2 regular expression to validate whether a string (from tokenized text) is a positive number, ideally for any value of the string that would work with, for example, `scanf("%f", &num)` in C. So that includes exponential floating-point representations like `1e9`.

I am using an unpublished framework, one not of my choosing, and I cannot change the framework code. The only method available in the framework to do the required validation is to provide it an RE2 regular expression.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466002) has several non-comprehensive answers and [one really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466218/52963) from tchrist that appears to be a PCRE regular expression. Unfortunately it is not RE2-compatible. My tools require RE2.

Comment: You might want a language specific answer as there are different version of regex implemented in different high-level languages.

Comment: While the reference engine of RE2 (https://github.com/google/re2) is in C++, it is possible to use RE2 in many other languages: C, Erlang, JS, Go, Ruby, and even Perl. This question is not specific to any programming language. RE2 should be pretty much the same in all languages.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
^[+]?(?:(?:0*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)|(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?))(?:[Ee][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

It tests the entire string using `^` and `$`, so it would need modification to work on a substring. Depending on language/environment, `\` or other characters may need to be escaped.

Here's a Go program that builds up the regex and tests it:

https://play.golang.com/p/ENHu09Axug4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

// build up regexp string
const (
    optLeadingPlus            string = "[+]?"
    mantissaLessthanOne       string = "(?:0*\\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)"
    mantissaGreaterorequalOne string = "(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)"
    positiveFloatMantissa     string = "(?:" +
        mantissaLessthanOne +
        "|" +
        mantissaGreaterorequalOne +
        ")"
    optExponent         string = "(?:[Ee][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
    regexpPositiveFloat string = "^" + optLeadingPlus + positiveFloatMantissa + optExponent + "$"
)

var (
    rePosFloat *regexp.Regexp
)

// require regexp to compile before main
func init() {
    rePosFloat = regexp.MustCompile(regexpPositiveFloat)
}

// test a single token and show the result
func test(s string, expected bool) {
    r := rePosFloat.MatchString(s)
    msg := "passed:"
    if r != expected {
        msg = "FAILED>"
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v s=%v, match=%v\n", msg, s, r)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", regexpPositiveFloat)

    tnan := "5.13.7 +0-1 McGillicuddy"
    tzero := "0 +0 -0 .0 0. 0.0 00.00 0.000 .000 +00 -00 0000. " +
        ".0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 " +
        "0e50 0e-50 0e0 .0E000 +0e-1"
    tneg := "-2 -1 -3.2 -0.001 -.00001 -0.0000001E-99 " +
        "-.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 "
    tpos := "2 +2 2. +1 1. 1.3 +365.2425 .03 0.3 3.0 6.02e23 0.00001 .01 .00001 " +
        ".00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 " +
        "+.01 +.000000000000000000000000000000000000001 1e50 1e+50 1e-50 1E0 +.05E-9"

    for _, t := range strings.Split(tnan, " ") {
        test(t, false)
    }
    for _, t := range strings.Split(tzero, " ") {
        test(t, false)
    }
    for _, t := range strings.Split(tneg, " ") {
        test(t, false)
    }
    for _, t := range strings.Split(tpos, " ") {
        test(t, true)
    }
}
```

Thanks to tchrist both for that PCRE version and for the excellent test cases.