# Regex for (simple) positive float values

Tags: regex

This question has been asked a lot, but I haven't found an answer that matches my criteria.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466218/2092250 provides the best regex I have found to date:

```
^(?!(?:^[-+]?[0.]+(?:[Ee]|$)))(?!(?:^-))(?:(?:[+-]?)(?=[0123456789.])(?:(?:(?:[0123456789]+)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789]*))?|(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789]+))))(?:(?:[Ee])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]+))|))$
```

But it includes signs and scientific notation (which I would like to exclude). I have broken the test list from that answer into 3 groups:

**CORRECTLY MATCHES:**

```
2
2.
1
1.
1.3
.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
.03
0.3
3.0
```

**CORRECTLY MISMATCHES:**

```
-2
-1
0
+0
-0
.0
0.
-3.2
5.13.7
00.00
+00
-00
+0-1
0000.
McGillicuddy
.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0e50
0e-50
```

**MATCHES I WOULD LIKE TO EXCLUDE:**

```
+2
+1
+365.2425
6.02e23
1e50
1e+50
1e-50
```

How would I edit it to exclude the last group?

Comment: Can you state your criteria for matching in words? What does "CORRECTLY MISMATCHES" mean?

Comment: Try [`^(?!0\d|[0.]*$)\d*(?:\.\d*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/dGpO2G/1)

Comment: this would not match any number with leading `0` like `00, 01, 034.24`. this might be desired if padding is occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?![0.]*$)(\d+)?\.?\d*$
```

See at https://regex101.com/r/BQix56/latest

`^` start of string

`(?!...)` negative lookahead asserting that the following is not met

- `[0.]*$` string contains only `0`s or `.`s or is empty

`(\d+)?` optional numbers before decimal point

`\.?` optional decimal point

`\d*` any amount of numbers after decimal point (or any amount of numbers if there is no decimal point)

`$` end of string